# CMake: what does " SET(PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED NOT ${PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED})" means?

Tags: c++, build, cmake

```
# If the user hasn't told use specifically what they want, build only
# a static library.

IF(NOT DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED AND NOT DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC)
   SET(PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC TRUE)
   SET(PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED FALSE)
ENDIF(NOT DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED AND NOT DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC)

IF(DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED AND NOT DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC)
    SET(PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED NOT ${PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED})
ENDIF(DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED AND NOT DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC)

IF(NOT DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED AND DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC)
    SET(PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED NOT ${PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC})
ENDIF(NOT DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED AND DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC)
```

what does "SET(PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED NOT ${PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED})"means? before those snippet i cann't see any definition of PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED variable

Comment: Seems it's intended to be set by the user of a package. Basically the statement should reverse the (boolean) value of `PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First 4 lines take the 2 "boolean" variables PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC and PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED, and if they are both not defined it sets them to a default value
- Second 3 lines invert the value of PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED if only PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED is defined, whatever its initial value is. **Weird!**
- Final 3 lines takes the inverted value of PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC and assign it to PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED if only PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC is defined

However, the behaviour overall seems a little bit weird. My guess is that this (second three lines):

```
IF(DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED AND NOT DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC)
    SET(PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED NOT ${PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED})
ENDIF(DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED AND NOT DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC)
```

should be:

```
IF(DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED AND NOT DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC)
    SET(PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC NOT ${PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED})
ENDIF(DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED AND NOT DEFINED PODOFO_BUILD_STATIC)
```

In this way it makes much more sense: if only one of the 2 variables is defined, it sets the other to the opposite value.

> what does "SET(PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED NOT ${PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED})"means? before those snippet i cann't see any definition of PODOFO_BUILD_SHARED variable

The variable might be define beforehand outside the file in several ways (e.g. from command line, or setting a cached variable through `cmake-gui`)

Comment: i thought it the same way you are, but it sames not reasonale

Comment: [here](https://github.com/Universefei/podofomemo/blob/master/podofo/CMakeLists.txt) is the original source code

Comment: @FeiLunzhou See my updated answer. I think you can report a bug.